# How to add <hr> after every new category

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I have a array of object called elements, and the objects have two values (`name` and `category`).

```
[
  {name : 'key1', category : 'tech'},
  {name : 'key2', category : 'tech'},
  {name : 'key3', category : 'tech'},
  {name : 'cable1' , category : 'hard'}
  {name : 'cable2' , category : 'hard'}
  {name : 'cable3' , category : 'hard'}
  {name : 'cable4' , category : 'hard'}
]
```

I want to display all names but add an `<hr>` whenever reaches a new **category**

Please help and thank you of helping.

Comment: please share the array of objects

Comment: Adding the code you tried will be much more helpful in this case, otherwise the answer will be closed as off-topic.

Comment: I've added the array, and for the code I didn't a solution to do that

Comment: All answers are good but array should be sorted by category then these implementation work fine. Otherwise same categories will be shown in multiple places. Consider it if you want to group name by category.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would first group your objects by category using [Array.prototype.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce), then iterate over each category using [Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```js
const data = [
  {name : 'key1', category : 'tech'},
  {name : 'wire1' , category : 'misc'},
  {name : 'key2', category : 'tech'},
  {name : 'cable1' , category : 'hard'},
  {name : 'key3', category : 'tech'},
  {name : 'cable2' , category : 'hard'},
  {name : 'wire2' , category : 'misc'}
];

const dataMap = data.reduce((acc, x) => {
  acc[x.category] = [...(acc[x.category] || []), x];
  return acc;
}, {});

const html = Object.entries(dataMap).map(([cat, items]) => {
  return items.map(item => `<div>${item.name} ${item.category}</div>`).join('');
}).join('<hr>');

document.getElementById('app').innerHTML = html;
```

```html
<div id="app"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

How about something like:

```
prev_category = undefined;
elements.forEach(function(e) {
  if (i > 0 && e.category != prev_category) {
    console.log('<hr>');
  }

  prev_category = e.category;
  console.log(e.name);
});
```

(of course, you can replace the `console.log()` commands with whatever you really want to do with those texts, e.g. append them to one big string)

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this,

```
var category;
$.each(object,function(i,objval)
{
   console.log(objval['name']);
   if(category != "" && category != objval['category'])
   {
     console.log("<hr>");
   }
   category = objval['category'];
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Iterate the object and use template literals to create the dom and check if the index of the array is not same as length then add an `hr`

```js
let elements = [{
    name: 'key',
    category: 'tech'
  },
  {
    name: 'cable',
    category: 'hard'
  }
]
let str = '';

elements.forEach(function(item, index) {
  str += `<div class='elem'><span>${item.name}</span><span> ${item.category}</span></div>`
  if (index !== elements.length - 1) {
    str += `<hr>`
  }
});
document.getElementById('container').innerHTML = str
```

```html
<div id='container'></div>
```

If you are looking for just border then use css pseudo selector

```js
let elements = [{
    name: 'key',
    category: 'tech'
  },
  {
    name: 'cable',
    category: 'hard'
  }
]
let str = '';

elements.forEach(function(item, index) {
  str += `<div class='elem'><span>${item.name}</span><span> ${item.category}</span></div>`

});
document.getElementById('container').innerHTML = str
```

```css
.elem:not(:last-child) {
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div id='container'></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically you need to sort the data by category first then, render the element, I use react code  as example

```js
const data = [
  {
    name: "Huawei",
    category: "phone"
  },
  {
    name: "Iphone",
    category: "phone"
  },
  {
    name: "Refacoring Improving the design of existing code",
    category: "book"
  },
  {
    name: "Python Crash Course",
    category: "book"
  },
  {
    name: "My heart will go on",
    category: "music"
  },
  {
    name: "I'm your angel",
    category: "music"
  }
];

function generateCom(data) {
  let listComps = [];
  let category = "";

  // sort the data by category
  data.sort((a, b) => (a.category > b.category ? 1 : -1));

  // generate the component by category
  data.forEach((ele, idx) => {
    if (idx === 0) {
      listComps.push(<h3>{ele.category}</h3>);
      listComps.push(<li>{ele.name}</li>);
      category = ele.category;
      return;
    }

    if (ele.category === category) {
      listComps.push(<li>{ele.name}</li>);
    } else {
      listComps.push(<hr />);
      listComps.push(<h3>{ele.category}</h3>);
      listComps.push(<li>{ele.name} </li>);
      category = ele.category;
    }
  });
  return listComps;
}
```

can refer to the example 
https://codesandbox.io/embed/6x0p7908qw